# <img src display exact location but no image

Tags: php, html, image, src, codeigniter-4

Hi i want to load an previously uploaded image via id the the controller passes the correct location to the view but the view don not eco the image if i inspect on the view page i find it shows the correct id and location but do not render the image ?

Problem area:

```
   <img src="<?php echo $jobcard['item_image']; ?>" style='height:150px;' alt="item_image">
```

My View:

```
<?php
$title = "Edit Job Card";
require_once __DIR__.'/../templates/header.php';
$jobcard = $jobcard[0];

?>
<title><? echo $title; ?></title>
<?php if (session()->getFlashdata('error') !== NULL) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo session()->getFlashdata('error'); session()->setFlashdata('error', NULL); ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (session()->getFlashdata('success') !== NULL) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo session()->getFlashdata('success'); session()->setFlashdata('success', NULL); ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="list-jobcards"><button class="btn btn-info">Back</button></a>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h1 class="greenicons"style= "font-size: 14px;"> Update Customer Information</h1>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $jobcard['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="text" name="job_number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['job_number']; ?>">
                                <label >Job Number</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="test" name="customer_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['customer_name']; ?>">
                                <label >Customer Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <label>Delivery Address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="delivery_address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['delivery_address']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <label>Customer Contact Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" name="customer_contact_number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['customer_contact_number']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <label>Customer Query</label>
                                <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['query']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <label>Artisan</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="artisan" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['artisan']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <label>Department</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['department']; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                        <label>Special_notes</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="special_notes" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['special_notes']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm">
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <label>Items Required</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="items_required" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['items_required']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm">
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <label>Feedback to Customer</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="feedback" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $jobcard['feedback']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm">
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                    <input id="item_image_after"  accept='image/*'  onchange="readURL(this)" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_image_after" type="file" value="<?php echo $jobcard['item_image_after']; ?>">
                                                    <label class="align-top" for="item_image_after">Image After</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Preview" id="img" style='height:150px;'>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm">
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                    <a id="item_image"   class="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_image" type="file" value=""></a>
                                                    <label class="align-top" for="item_image">Image Before</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <img src="<?php echo $jobcard['item_image']; ?>" style='height:150px;' alt="item_image">
                                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="update">Update</button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../templates/footer.php';
?>
```

My Controler:

```
 public function editJobcard()
    {
        $jobcard_model = new \App\Models\Jobcard_Model();

        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $upd = $jobcard_model->update($id, $_POST);

            // Image After //
            $file = $this->request->getFile('item_image_after');
            if ($file->isValid()) {
                $newName = $file->getRandomName();
                $file->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads/' . $upd . '/', $newName);
                $file_location = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/' . $upd . '/' . $newName;
            } else {
                $file_location = "";
            }
            $jobcard_model->update($upd, ['item_image_after' => $file_location]);

            $session = session();
            unset($_POST['update']);
            if ($upd==true) {
                $session->setFlashdata('success', "Job Card edited successfully");
            } else {
                $session->setFlashdata('error', "There was an error editing the Job Card , please contact the administrator");
            }
        }
        $data = [];
        $data['jobcard'] = $jobcard_model->findById($id);

        return view('/edit/edit_jobcard', $data);
    }



My Model:


<?php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Jobcard_Model extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'jobcards';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;

    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField = 'updated_at';

    protected $allowedFields = ['id', 'customer_name', 'delivery_address', 'customer_email', 'customer_contact_number', 'artisan', 'department', 'special_notes', 'items_required', 'item_image', 'item_image_after', 'date_created','feedback','query', 'job_number'];

    function getJobcards()
    {
        // Return fetched data
        $query = $this->findAll();
        return $query;
    }


    function findById($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db()->query("SELECT * FROM 5ujobcards WHERE id = '$id'");
        return $query->getResultArray();
    }

}
?>
```

my script:

```
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.querySelector("#img").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So whats in `$jobcard['item_image']` NOTE: There is way too much code here

Comment: Sorry for all the code RiggsFolly. were not sure what code will be needed and what not it is my first upload i will try next time to get to the problem point only. here is wat the $jobcard['item_image'] point to: src="/home/devintouchsoftco/public_html/writable/uploads/1/1621837377_8b5ec5302bc81628487c.jpg"

Comment: you have to put an url that is pointed to that image, if you put it into browser address box it will show that image.  like as `https://your-domain/an-image.jpg`

Comment: Thanx Moshiur the i think you are on the right path. how do i tell my <img src=""> to show the image located at <php echo $jobcard['item_image'] /> and not the location

Answer (score 0):

/home/devintouchsoftco/public_html/writable/uploads/1/1621837377_8b5ec5302bc81628487c.jpg seems to be location in your drive. But to show the image it should be a url like : http://localhost/writable/uploads/1/1621837377_8b5ec5302bc81628487c.jpg

Comment: Thanks Vinith but the problem is the path is on a server and  the controller generates the path and img names / id and the controller also calls that same data back this is the part i included. The controller calls the exact location and id but the <img do not render the image?

Comment: thanx RiggsFolly , ok i think i have a partial solution i will have to remove all code from src like src="" and give src an id like id="item_image" and then i will need a function or script to refer to a site location like href="<php echo $jobcard['item_image'] />". but this will result in a link and will cause a page error 404 ?

Comment: href="<php echo $jobcard['item_image'] />" no good result in a broken image that is a click link leading to page not found

Comment: You need to just store the name of the image file in "item_image" field of the jobcard table. Then in the src tag, you can generate the url using "your domain name" + "location of the folder in which the image file resides with respect to the domain root folder" + $jobcard['item_image']